# Firebase Error : Photo URL too long. (React.js, React-Router, React-Router Action)

Tags: reactjs, firebase, input, react-router

Where im sending file information

```js
   <Form
        method='post'
        className={styled['upload-photo-container']}
        encType='multipart/form-data'
      >

  <Input
          name='file'
          type='file'
          accept='image/*'
        />
</Form>
```

React Router action that im taking file data from request

```js
export async function action({ request }) {
 const user = auth.currentUser;

  const data = await request.formData();

// Photo Update
  const file= data.get('file');
  const photoPropRef = collection(db, 'photoProp');
  const position = data.get('position');
  const size = data.get('size');



    try {
      if (file) {
        const libraryImage = await this.openLibrary();
        await updateProfile(auth.currentUser, {
          displayName: user.displayName,
          photoURL: ????,
        });
        await setDoc(doc(photoPropRef, userInfo.uid), {
          position,
          size,
        });
     
        return redirect('/profile');
      }
    } catch (err) {
      return handleError(err);
    }
```

- This code is Writen in React.js and React Router Version 6.4
- The Error im taking is Firebase Error : Photo URL too long.
- I was getting That Error when i implement this code to my action:

```js
     if (file) {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
      reader.onload = async () => {
         await updateProfile(auth.currentUser, {
          displayName: user.displayName,
          photoURL: reader.result,
        });
        
      };
    }
```

- How do i update my profile without this Error ?

I was try to get images from my computer and send it successfully to backend Firebase by using updateProfile. But i came cross with Firebase Error : Photo URL too long.

Comment: This may not seem obvious, but have you tried using shorter file URLs?

Comment: @DrewReese Yes sir, I have try many images. Same Error every time